# Java DriveAPI - how to add people to a shared file

Tags: java, android, file, permissions, google-drive-api

I am uploading some files on google drive and make them public (anyone/reader) however, I need to add people to the files (like you would do in the Drive App) so I can later read those files from those accounts.

Below a code snippet I use - as you can see I am setting the file permissions

```
public Task<String> uploadFileToGoogleDrive(String path) {

    if (folderId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "uploadFileToGoogleDrive: folder id not present");
        isFolderPresent().addOnSuccessListener(id -> folderId = id)
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't create file.", exception));
    }

    return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {

        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(path);

        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName(filePath.getName());
        fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
        fileMetadata.setMimeType(Utils.getFileMimeType(filePath));

        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(Utils.getFileMimeType(filePath), filePath);
        File file = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .setIncludePermissionsForView("published")
                .execute();
        Log.i(TAG, "uploadFileToGoogleDrive: " + " File ID: " + file.getId());

        File permissionsMetadata = new File();
        permissionsMetadata.setShared(true);
        Permission p = new Permission();
        p.setType("anyone");
        p.setRole("reader");
        permissionsMetadata.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(new Permission[]{p}));
        mDriveService.permissions().create(file.getId(),p).execute();

        return file.getId();
    });
}
```

I tried adding people from Permissions somehow, or Metadata but did not find a way

Answer (score 0):

Solved, permission was not properly set, should have used user and set the email address:

```
            accessPermission.setEmailAddress(email);
            accessPermission.setType("user");
            accessPermission.setRole("reader");
```